# Trying to get property 'dept_name' of non-object Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.8

I wonder why I get an error "Trying to get non-object" in my laravel blade file.

Code in my blade file

```
@foreach($calls as $call)
<tr>
 @if($call->counter_id === null)
 <td>{{ $call->department->dept_name }}</td>                
 <td>{{ $call->transaction->trans_name }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Call Model

```
public function call()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Call');
}
```

Department Model

```
public function department()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Department');
}
```

Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $calls = Call::all();

    return view('test', ['calls' => $calls]);
}
```

That code is seemingly correct. I provide the relationships in my model. I just want to know why it is getting that kind of error as I also figuring out why.

Comment: You can debug it, first of all close @endif , as if you're saying you're relationship is correctly setup try `dd($call->department)` and comment all other below code (within @foreach loop), if you're getting collection in return then you need to check column name, otherwise you're relationship is not correct, now i would suggest, always check from controller first, before rending into the blade dd($calls) in controller, is this your query `$calls = Calls::with(['department','transaction'])->get()` ?

Comment: try to `dd` for your object it should be empty show me resquest method in controller

Comment: @Vipertecpro nope my query is $calls = Call::all(). It works in other file except this one

Comment: Please show the model of Calls. Most probably it is App/Calls.php.

Comment: Please dd($calls); and check dept_name is there in that objects if not than you have to do some changes in your query or in your DB.

Comment: I dd it and the value of departments is there

Comment: I already edit my question with model

Comment: I debug it also using their foreign keys in call db and its okay

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug to see what exactly went wrong.

Try

```
var_dump( $call);;
die;
```

or

```
dd($call);
die;
```

See whats coming from inside as dept_name .
if you use **dd** you will see the data in **relations** tag.
If you dont see any relations like department , then your model setup is not Okay.
Otherwise
It could be name mismatch in database column or attributes not defined
in model class.

Comment: when use dd() in laravel,no need to give die or exit,dd automatically exit the code

Answer (score 0):

```
in your controller make sure

$calls = Calls::with('department')->get();

return view('--your blade file--',compact('calls'));
}
```